# Ordering an array of strings while avoiding duplicates

Tags: c++

So say I have:

`string array1[5] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "F"};
 string array2[5] = {"A", "C", "G", "F", "D"};
 string result[100];`

I'm trying to make the string result[100] compose of non-duplicates from array1 and array2 while being in a sequential order of array1[0] then array2[0] then array1[1] then array2[1] etc.

(e.g.) `string result[100] = {"A", "B", "C", "G", "D", "F"};`

This is the code I have thus far:

```
for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    result[i] = array2[i];
}

for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<100; j++) {
        if (result[j] == "") {
            result[j] = array1[i];
            break;
        }
        if (result[j] == array1[i]) break;
    }
}
```

This code avoids duplicates, but not in the correct order I want. I can't wrap my head around solving this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i  think std::set would do the trick

Comment: @Debabrata `std::set` doesn't preserve a _sort order_.

Comment: Yeah that's right  ...my bad

Comment: `std::set` preserves _sort_ order, not _insert_ order.

Comment: Break it into two pieces:  First, can you have a method that coughs up elements from the two arrays in the correct order (hint: it can keep local state to remember which array and which index is next).  Second, can you have a method that appends to your final result only if the new item to append isn't the same as the last item already there.  Third: can you combine them into one function (hint: first ask if you need to bother doing that).

Comment: did you explain your code to your rubber duck? mine didnt understand it

Comment: Kindly clarify, are the `array1` and `array2` sequences individually already composed of unique items? In your sample they are, but is that *guaranteed* ? Further, are they guaranteed to be the same magnitude (same number of elements in each array) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully working, i just wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string array1[5]= {"A","B","C","D","F"};
    string array2[5]= {"A","C","G","F","D"};
    vector<string> result;
    bool check1;
    bool check2;

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]);i++){
        bool check1= check2= false;
        if(result.size() == 0 && array1[i] != array2[i]){
            result.push_back(array1[i]);
            result.push_back(array2[i]);
        }
        else if(result.size() == 0 && array1[i] == array2[i]){
            result.push_back(array1[i]);
        }
        else {
            for(int j=0; j<result.size(); j++){
                if(array1[i] == result[j])
                    check1= true;
            }
            if(!check1)
                result.push_back(array1[i]);

            for(int j=0; j<result.size(); j++){
                if(array2[i] == result[j])
                    check2= true;
            }
            if(!check2)
                result.push_back(array2[i]);
        }
    }
    for(vector<string>::iterator it= result.begin(); it != result.end(); it++){
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach creates a `std::map` so that only unique strings are kept, but also stores the indices so that a second map can be created with the elements in the correct sequence.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec{
        {"A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "W"},
        {"A", "C", "G", "F", "D"}};
    using Index = std::pair<size_t, size_t>;
    std::map<std::string, Index> intermediate;

    for(size_t row{}; row < vec.size(); ++row)
        for(size_t element{}; element < vec[row].size(); ++element)
            intermediate.insert(std::make_pair( // Won't overwrite
                vec[row][element],              // Insert string in map
                Index{element, row}));          // Store index for sequencing

    std::map<Index, std::string> result;
    for(auto&&[string, index] : intermediate)   // C++17 structured bindings
        result[index] = string;                 // Map sorts by original position

    for(auto& element : result)
        std::cout << element.second << ' ';
}
```